# How to enable new added row clickable in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with each row having a class ".clickablerow" and I defined onclick function when click on this row, a dialog will show up then I can insert above or below some text as new row. The question is, though I've added ".clickablerow" to these new added rows, they are actually not clickable and no such dialog showing up.

My code is like:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function(){

           var i = $(this).rowIndex;
           var html = "<tr class='clickable-row' > <td> a test </td></tr>";

           $('#table_id > tbody > tr').eq(i).after(html);
});
```

HTML:

```
<head>
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="./static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/jquery.expander.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
....
<head>

<body>
....
  <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr class='clickable-row' >
          <td style="border: 0;"> Initial message ....</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
....
</body>
```

If I click on the row, a new row with class 'clickable-row' will be added, however, that new row is not clickable. Any idea are welcome!
Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

```js
$('#table_id').on('click', '.clickable-row', function() {

  debugger;
  var i = this.rowIndex;
  var html = "<tr class='clickable-row' > <td> a test " + i + "</td></tr>";

  $('#table_id > tbody > tr').eq(i).after(html);
});
```

```css
table#table_id {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#table_id tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#table_id tr:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#table_id th {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#table_id th,
#example td {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

#table_id td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
  <tbody>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://'>
      <td style="border: 0;"> Initial message ....</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: binding things to `$(document)` is not really the best for a number of reasons.. try to find an element closer to your target that exists when the page is rendered.  maybe `$('#table_id').on('click', '.clickable-row', function() {` for instance

Answer (score 2):

Just [delegate the `click` event](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to the `<table>` or the `<tbody>`:

```js
const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');

tableBody.onclick = (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  
  let row = target;
  
  while (!row.classList.contains('clickable-row') && row !== tableBody) row = row.parentElement;
  
  if (row === tableBody) {
     return; // Ignore the click if we could not find a .clickable-row
  }

  const newRow = tableBody.insertRow(target.rowIndex);

  newRow.className = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'clickable-row' : 'disabled-row';
  newRow.innerHTML = '<td>...</td>';
};
```

```css
table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

tr.disabled-row {
  background: #EEE;;
}

tr.clickable-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.clickable-row:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
    <tr class="clickable-row"><td>...</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With jQuery, you can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:
>
> ```
> $( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
>     console.log( $( this ).text() );
> });
> ```
>
> An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):
>
> ```
> $( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
>     console.log( $( this ).text() );
> });
> ```

The previous example would then look like this:

```js
$('#tableBody').on('click', '.clickable-row', (e) => {
  $(e.currentTarget).after(`<tr class=${ Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'clickable-row' : 'disabled-row' }><td>...</td></tr>`);
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

tr.disabled-row {
  background: #EEE;;
}

tr.clickable-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.clickable-row:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
    <tr class="clickable-row"><td>...</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```